# some table cell background color remains white though not declared anywhere

Tags: css

I am having a strange issue while trying to style a html table. The table has no background color set but some of the cells background color appear as white. Firebug says there is no background color set for those cells and I am out of ideas why this is happening.

The demo table can be seen from here: http://abc.lonelycloud.net/master-schedule/

I hope someone will help me finding out the issue. thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: You HAVE defined it, in http://abc.lonelycloud.net/wp-content/themes/reverie/css/foundation.min.css. If you have had a look in your console you would have immediately have found it (like i did)

Comment: @Diodeus thanks! I didn't know that. I will keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its being set on the Table Row.

```
tr{
     background: transparent;
}
```

Should get rid of it, but you should really just get rid of the background you set somewhere else in the CSS

Moral of the story is, don't forget that a background can come from a PARENT too!

Comment: Right.  Those rules are all being applied to the tr.  That last parameter says that (among other things) the background should be #F9F9F9 for those rows